Trigger WebSocket from Postman test suite
I am trying to write a test suite which has a scenario like this -

I have a RESTful Chat Controller with 5 different HTTP API's
One of the REST API's (lets say API #2) sends the response to a web socket (streaming chat response) and then responds back with 200 OK

In my test suite I need to trigger the web socket handshake and establish connection after API #2 is called. Is there a way to do this from the postman test suite?
